# My query returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, function, plsql, count, cursor

I am working on this function is pl/sql where I want to return one number, the amount of expressions.

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION media_f(
      p_media in varchar2,
      p_date in TIMESTAMP,
      p_sentiment in varchar2)

RETURN NUMBER
IS

  l_amount NUMBER;
CURSOR c_media IS
  SELECT COUNT() 
  FROM MEDIA
  WHERE MEDIA.DATES = p_date
    AND MEDIA.KIND = p_media
    AND MEDIA.POSITIVE_NEGATIVE = p_sentiment;


BEGIN
     open c_media;
     fetch c_media into l_amount;
     close c_media;

RETURN l_amount;
END;
```

When I try to use it like this:

```
select Project.MEDIA_F ('tv', '06-05-13', 'n') 
from MEDIA;
```

It return all the records from the table with either everywhere a 1 or a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using any columns from table in the `from` clause.  However, the SQL engine will still return one row for each row "generated" by the `from` clause.

Assuming you are using Oracle, just use `dual` instead of a table name:

```
select Project.MEDIA_F('tv', '06-05-13', 'n') 
from dual;
```

Most other databases don't require the `from` clause.